# Should Objective-C Custom Timer Class be in Model or Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, model-view-controller, nstimer

I've created a custom Timer Class with public API allowing access to a property timeLeft, and allowing the calling class to start and pause the timer, as well as a Boolean isTimerPaused.

I need the Timer to be initialized and started, and paused inside of my game loop for various situations. So I've gone ahead with initializing my timer in my game (model) as such:

```
#define timerDuration  10
    self.timer =[[Timer alloc] initWithTimerDurationInSeconds:timerDuration];
```

Here is a look at my Timer API:

```
@interface Timer : NSObject

-(id)initWithTimerDurationInSeconds:(NSTimeInterval)duration;

-(void)startTimer;
-(void)pauseTimer;


@property (nonatomic, getter = isTimerPaused)BOOL timerPaused;
@property (nonatomic)NSTimeInterval timeLeft;

@end
```

and my Timer implementation

```
#import "Timer.h"

@interface Timer ()

@property (nonatomic)NSTimeInterval timeRemaining;
@property (nonatomic)NSTimeInterval duration;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSDate *targetTime;

@end

@implementation Timer

-(id)initWithTimerDurationInSeconds:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        if (duration) _duration = duration;
        else NSLog(@"Must Initialize Timer With Duration");
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)startTimer
{
    self.targetTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:self.duration];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.05 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimerLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    self.timerPaused = NO;

}
-(void)pauseTimer
{
    self.timerPaused = !self.isTimerPaused;
    if (self.isTimerPaused)
    {
        self.timeRemaining = [self.targetTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        self.targetTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:self.timeRemaining];
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.05 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimerLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }

}

-(void)updateTimeLeft
{
    self.timeLeft = [self.targetTime timeIntervalSinceNow];

    if (self.timeLeft <=0)
    {
        [self.timer invalidate];
       ago", -timeLeft];
    }
}
@end
```

This all in theory will work great as I can start and stop my timer as needed inside of my game loop, and i can access time left to update my timer UILabel from my Controller.

My issue is this, If the timer were in my controller, I could simply update the label inside of the updateTimeLeft method.  With the timer in the model how do I go about refreshing UI Elements continuously.  My thought was to have some sort of continuous timer in my controller that would update the UILabel with the timeLeft property from the timer, but that seems inefficient and prone to being slightly inaccurate.

Thanks!

Comment: Controllers in proper MVC pattern should only alter state of model layer and current view(s). The best place for a timer would probably be some service inside the model layer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment tereško.  That's the conclusion I've sort of come up with.  The question is, how do I best update the corresponding UI element from the Controller?

Comment: Depends on the interpretation of MVC that you use. In something close-to-classical, you would have views that observe changes in model's state. When timer causes something to change in model layer, view detects this change and consequently requests data from model layer to illustrate this change. Unfortunately, most of people do not implement MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With the timer in the model how do I go about refreshing UI Elements continuously?

Move the timer out of your model.  Seriously.

Every graphic representation of MVC you will come across has a nice solid line between the View layer and the Model layer, and there's a reason for that.  If the model knows too much about the view, then your application becomes overly data-driven and bloated.  The same goes for the opposite.  Plug the timer into your controller, and route updates to the model from the controller to prevent any leakage of responsibilities into the wrong parts of your application.

Comment: Thanks CodaFi.  Your comment made me sit here for a second and think about why I wanted the timer in my controller in the first place. When I said the reason aloud, it became clear that I could still achieve the desired functionality in a much less complicated, convoluted way.  The goal here was to have my game loop cycle alongside the timer.  Seems silly now but this can be achieved by listening to the timer in the controller and calling a method in the game model to the effect of -(void)nextQuestion;

Comment: One more thing to add.  The conceptual gap in my knowledge that I had to overcome to properly achieve what I was after was using delegates.  I needed to configure my Timer Class as a delegate and implement the delegate methods in my view controller.  This way, I was able to inform the view controller when the timer had either changed or expired and update my UI accordingly. Fundamental iOS MVC, but hopefully this will help another rookie like myself! cheers